# Associating multiple e-mail addresses with ASP.NET MembershipProvider accounts

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

For a project I am currently working on, I am interested in allowing users to provide multiple e-mail addresses, both for contact purposes as well as providing address book-based social matching. I plan to write a custom membership provider (aspnet_Membership table is too heavy for my liking), but the MembershipProvider system only allows for one e-mail address per account.

What would be the best idea for using the membership provider system but allow for multiple e-mail addresses per user? Or should I avoid MembershipProvider completely and roll my own system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do this.  In addition to writing a custom MembershipProvider class, you will need to create a derived class from [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) to hold the additional e-mail address fields.  Instructions on how to do this are [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Seems like this might be a good place to put auth info for other services as well (like Facebook Connect or OpenID). Thanks!